# Three-way NAT: Forward wlan0 to both eth0 AND wlan1

Tags: networking, home-networking, raspberry-pi, nat

I set up a Raspberry 3 as a wifi-to-wifi access point to create my own subnet: I got an external WiFi adapter, and am now forwarding traffic from wlan1 to wlan0 and vice versa (following [this tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/overview) on Adafruit)

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Oct 13 23:35:31 2016
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2:120]
:INPUT ACCEPT [2:120]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [9:660]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Oct 13 23:35:31 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Oct 13 23:35:31 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [8:559]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [6:404]
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o wlan1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Oct 13 23:35:31 2016
```

This works perfectly fine so far. However, I have a few devices that I would prefer to connect via a wired connection and a little 8 port switch.

I thought it would be as straightforward as replicating the two `-A FORWARD` rules for the respective `wlan0` and `eth0` combinations, but that does not work:

```
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o wlan1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

As soon as I connect anything to `eth0` things get awfully slow or stop working completely, and the wire-connected devices never connect to the internet.

The goal would be that all devices can talk to each other, independent of whether they're connected via LAN or WLAN, and that they can all connect to the internet as well. Is that feasable with the current hardware setup?

Comment: That should work. Are you using unique subnets on all three interfaces?

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what I'm doing here. I set up the wifi AP with hostapd and installed an isc-dhcp server, that is now configured to work both on wlan1 and eth0. Other than that, my assumption was that plugging in the cable would be enough. Do I need to set up more stuff?

Comment: That depends on what you actually want. Is it acceptable for wlan1 and eth0 be on the same network (bridged)? Or do you want separate networks which are perhaps even firewalled from each other?